# There is an error “Mismatched anonymous define() module” when using Requirejs and Office.js

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

There is an error “Mismatched anonymous define() module” to block our Addin page loading time to time as following screenshot.

This is an Requirejs error. But it cannot be reproduced unless importing Office.js.

So is there anything I should care about when using Office.js and Requirejs at the same time?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue. The issue has now been fixed and you should no longer see this error. Thanks,
Trang

Comment: This is a known issue. The team will be looking into making Office.js compatible with Require.js, but we don't have a timeline for this fix.